# Best way to Pass value from one page to another php

Tags: php

Normally i use `id` to take database values from one page to another. like a example format provided

```
 location.href='edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $id?>
```

1. Is this way be problematic?
2. Is this ok or can i adopt any other way to pass values from one page to another.
3. which is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you do anything else with this data?  LIke say use it in a mysql query?  If so this could be problematic if the data is not properly escaped and lead to an sql injection.

Comment: am using to take data all around the site. then what will be the best to avoid sql Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing IDs around is simple and it gets the job done. You should expect people to try changing the id to see what happens, but as long as you don't show users pages they shouldn't be able to hit, it sounds great.

While I think the query string is right for what you're doing, there are more options:

- POSTing a form (requires JavaScript, extra work to add hidden form fields, and it's usually a worse experience for the user if they refresh or use the history)
- [Using sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), which gets very messed up if your user has multiple tabs open, adds extra stress on your servers, and if the user takes a long time between clicks (esp. if they leave a browser open for a few hours and come back), the links will stop working because the session expires
- [Using cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), which also gets messed up if your user has multiple tabs open, but (unlike sessions) doesn't stress your server or expire if you don't want them to

Comment: then i think you are suggesting me to continue what am doing?

Comment: Given that you meet the requirements that @ojrac put forth - mainly that you're providing the necessary security around the pages that you're passing the querystrings to.  If, however, all you do is limit the hyperlinks that are loaded in the user's browser, that will not stop malicious users from "hacking" your querystring to see what else they shouldn't be seeing/updating/deleting/etcetera.

Comment: Yeah. My security comment applies to all of these, to some degree -- I gave the other options to show why I think what you're doing now is the best choice.